# Dynamically increment input ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm developing a chat box application using iframe and jquery. I am able to dynamically create the iframes with unique ids but not the inputs. I need the input ids to access the text for each chat box.
index.html

```
<body>
    <p>+</p>
    <div></div>

scripts.js

$(function () {

    var id = 1;
    $('p').on('click', function() {

       $('<iframe />', {
            name: 'frame',
            id:   id,
            sandbox: 'allow-forms allow-top-navigation allow-scripts allow-modals allow-same-origin',
            src: 'iframe.html'
            }).appendTo('div');

        $('input').attr('id', id);

        id++;  

    })
});

iframe.html

<form name="frame">
<input type="text" id="0" class="chatBoxes" value="type your message"></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you determining the `id` attribute isn't incrementing?  When I run the code below and inspect the `input` tag the `id` increments with each click:

http://jsbin.com/fusidijane/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm looking to have a unique ID attached to each input and the input should be inside of the iframes created.

Comment: You could try: `var frame =$('<iframe />', { //attributes here }); frame.find('input').attr('id', id); $('div').append(frame);`

Comment: Thanks! I changed the code but still getting the same result, an input id that doesn't increment.

Comment: any other ideas? Appreciate it!